# Stored procedure to select between dates?

Tags: sql, t-sql, date, stored-procedures

I am writing a stored proc to Select information, i would like it to only select between dates?

**This is what it looks like now:**

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[AutoCompleate] 
 @DateFrom datetime,
 @DateTo datetime,
 @SearchField varchar(50)
 AS

 -- V1.0 : ShaunM : 15 jun 2012
    --  AutoComplete textbox

 exec ('
 SELECT DISTINCT ' +
 @SearchField + ' FROM SchemaAudit 
             ORDER BY ' + @SearchField +' ASC')
```

I want the select to run for entry's into the database between @DateTo and DateFrom, Does any one know how to do this?

Comment: It would help if you posted the table structure for SchemaAudit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of exec you should be using [sp_executesql](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx) which allows for use of parameters, avoiding a risk of Sql injection and avoiding potential issues with dates passed as strings. First parameter is a query, second is a list of parameters and their types and the rest are parameter values.

```
alter PROCEDURE [dbo].[AutoCompleate] 
     @DateFrom datetime,
     @DateTo datetime,
     @SearchField varchar(50)
     AS

     -- V1.0 : ShaunM : 15 jun 2012
        --  AutoComplete textbox

    declare @sql nvarchar(max)
    set @sql = 'SELECT DISTINCT ' 
             + quotename(@SearchField)
             + ' FROM SchemaAudit'
             + ' WHERE [Date] between @from AND @to ORDER BY '
             + quotename(@SearchField)
             + ' ASC'

     exec sp_executesql @sql, 
                        N'@from datetime, @to datetime', 
                        @from = @DateFrom, @to = @DateTo
```

Now, about start and end dates, what exactly you want to do?

Comment: Invalid column name startdate, Invalid Column name EndDate

Comment: Wouldn't this still be subject to injection attack due to the @SearchField usage?

Comment: @Chris- Yes, it should be quoted. Editing.

Comment: @Pomster Column names are yours. Could you please post a working query (non-dynamic sql kind of query? Simple select?)

Comment: Start and end date i don't what they do, u guys keep putting them there? i just what the query to be between my two date parameters

Comment: @Pomster I copied your original alter proc, section `I would like it to do something like:`

Comment: Yes i was trying to give the idea of what i wanted, sorry i see every one now has thought to use start and end date.

Comment: Thanks it says invalid column name date

Comment: @Pomster Instead of [Date] put your date column name.

Answer (score 2):

Use [BETWEN](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174081.aspx)

```
Where StartDate BETWEEN @DateFrom and @DateTo
```

EDIT: As Nalaka526 pointed out, I missed the EndDate, 
You can't use BETWEEN with two fields, You need to cast it to varchar and use >= and <= to compare between the range. Curt solution is doing that.

```
 WHERE StartDate >= ' + Convert(varchar(20),@DateFrom) + 'AND EndDate >= ' + Convert(varchar(20),@DateTo) + '
```

Comment: Could you put it in the same format as my exec( .... I can't get these commers right (')

Comment: `exec ('
     SELECT DISTINCT ' +
     @SearchField + ' FROM SchemaAudit WHERE StartDate >= ' +Convert(varchar(20), @DateFrom) + 'AND WHERE EndDate >= ' + Convert(varchar(20),@DateTo) + '
                 ORDER BY ' + @SearchField +' ASC')`

Comment: Convert, varchar and 20 are all underlined in red?

Answer (score 1):

You would need to `CAST` the date parameters as `varchar`:

```
exec ('
     SELECT DISTINCT ' +
     @SearchField + ' FROM SchemaAudit WHERE StartDate >= "' + CAST(@DateFrom as varchar(20)) + '" AND EndDate >= "' + CAST(@DateTo as varchar(20)) + '"
                 ORDER BY ' + @SearchField +' ASC')
```

Comment: @HackedByChinese Cheers, there were some other syntax issues too which I've now corrected

Comment: Cast , Datefrom, DateTo and the numbers 20 are all underlined in red.

Answer (score -1):

Ignoring the fact that this technique could leave you vulnerable to a SQL injection attack, you need to use `Convert` to convert the date to a varchar

```
Convert(varchar(20), DateTime, 111)
```